# Set headers correct for DICOM server to communicate with my Angular 5 application

Tags: server, header, dicom

I currently am working to retrieve a DICOM file by using my Angular application. The problem is that I cannot retrieve any data since No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the DICOM server. I am cheating with a enable CORS extension in chrome to debug the data but in the end I will need to set those headers right. Does anyone know how to set the correct headers on my DICOM server? It runs on a wildfly server and it is set up by this link [link to dcm4chee setup](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Installation).

The error can be seen in the image below
[image]

Comment: I don't know how to configure the wildfly server. but as an alternative solution for you problem, you can proxy your api calls through the server that is hosing your webapp, and than you can make all your api calls to localhost. nginx example: https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2014/08/20/hosting-the-node-api-in-nginx-with-a-reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added headers in the wildfly itself as you can see in the image below. This is located in the standalone.xml file in the wildfly directory. The headers contained to allow all, giving my application access to it.

[image]